why does VBA not continue to loop if if statement is false
I am trying to copy certain range if criteria is met. But I got run time error 13 : type mismatch , when it turns false to the statement. if the statement is false then it should do nothing and continue with the loop of checking again for the next counter
Sub Breakdown()

Dim Filter As Worksheet
Set Filter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter")
Dim Breakdown As Worksheet
Set Breakdown = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Breakdown")

Dim counter As Integer
Dim lr As Integer
Dim pastecounter As Integer

lr = Filter.Range("B" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
pastecounter = 8

For counter = 8 To lr

 If Filter.Range("BK" & counter).Value = "For Processing" Then
  Filter.Select
  Range("BM" & counter & ":BN" & counter).Copy
  Breakdown.Select
  Range("A" & pastecounter & ":B" & pastecounter).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  pastecounter = pastecounter + 1
 End If

Next counter

End Sub



The way to debug these types of problems is to break them apart.  The line with the If is doing 3 different things.  Do the str concatenation, getting the Value, and the comparison on separate lines.  Do that, and the error will tell you what your problem is.

Please, make a break point on the code line pastecounter = 8 and see what value does lr have. Then, you do not need to select anything... Try using a single code line Filter.Range("BM" & counter & ":BN" & counter).Copy Range("A" & pastecounter) and comment all the other lines, except pastecounter increment...

its shows the same error pointing to the if statement ,
it did  copy some range but when its once a false result it does not proceed checking to the next range

I guess Filter.Range("BK" & counter).Value is hitting an error  (like #N/A, or something)
You'd better check for errors too, like follows:
Option Explicit

Sub Breakdown()

    Dim Filter As Worksheet
        Set Filter = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Filter")
    Dim Breakdown As Worksheet
        Set Breakdown = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Breakdown")
    
        With Filter
        
            Dim lr As Long
                lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
            
            Dim pastecounter As Long
                pastecounter = 8
            
            Dim counter As Long
                For counter = 8 To lr
                
                    Select Case True
                        Case IsError(.Range("BK" & counter).Value)
                        
                        Case .Range("BK" & counter).Value = "For Processing"
                            .Range("BM" & counter & ":BN" & counter).Copy Breakdown.Range("A" & pastecounter)
                            pastecounter = pastecounter + 1
                    End Select
            
                Next
        End With

End Sub

Where I also:

used direct reference to worksheets instead of those Select/Activesheet, which is a dangerous way of coding

declared all integer values as Long, to avoid errors should you handle rows indexes greater than 32767


